# Python passing a string value from a table to a function

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to go through a list of items and passing each one to a function one by one to create an Excel file with the same name as the argument passed.  I am getting the error below which I believe is related to the '/' in the String name.  Can anyone advise how I get it to ignore this?

```
>>> test.createExcel(filename)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#97>", line 1, in <module>
    test.createExcel(filename)
  File "C:\Users\danie\OneDrive\JVC\project1.py", line 52, in createExcel
    wb2.save(modelname+'.xlsx')
  File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 392, in save
    save_workbook(self, filename)
  File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 291, in save_workbook
    archive = ZipFile(filename, 'w', ZIP_DEFLATED, allowZip64=True)
  File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\zipfile.py", line 1240, in __init__
    self.fp = io.open(file, filemode)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '14 A4/32GB BLU.xlsx'
```

Answer (score 0):

A filename cannot contain any of the following characters: \ / : * ? " < > |

In ur case， u could replace ur filename using `str.replace('/','-')` or any other character u'd like to.

eg:

```
wb.save(filename.replace('\','-'))
```

Or using the regular expression to replace it may work well.